# XQuery Distinct XML tag

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

I am trying create a XQuery to generate a following details of the xml tag used with the no. of occurrence

Book- 3 occurrence
Article-2 occurrence
conference - 1 occurrence

Is this possible? i've been trying but it does not work

```
<test>
   <book>
        <year>1992</year>
   ....
   </book>
   <article>
        <year>1992</year>
   ....
   </article>
   <conference>
        <year>1992</year>
   ....
   </conference>
   <article>
        <year>1992</year>
   ....
   </article>
   <book>
        <year>1992</year>
   ....
   </book>
   <book>
        <year>1992</year>
   ....
   </book>
</test>
```

Comment: is that a xquery to get the distinct type of Xml tag used in the XML file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use this pure and simple XPath 2.0 expression**:

```
for $name in distinct-values(/*/*/name())
 return
   ($name, count(index-of(/*/*/name(),$name)),'&#xA;')
```

**When this expression is evaluated against the provided XML document:**

```
<test>
   <book>
        <year>1992</year>
   ....
   </book>
   <article>
        <year>1992</year>
   ....
   </article>
   <conference>
        <year>1992</year>
   ....
   </conference>
   <article>
        <year>1992</year>
   ....
   </article>
   <book>
        <year>1992</year>
   ....
   </book>
   <book>
        <year>1992</year>
   ....
   </book>
</test>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
 book 3
 article 2 
 conference 1
```

Comment: But one question, how can i add a where clause of year="XXXX" in it?

Comment: @user1004413, You need to learn XPath: `for $name in distinct-values(/*/*[year='1992']/name())
 return
   ($name, count(index-of(/*/*[year='1992']/name(),$name)),'&#xA;')`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach that should work if the `group by` syntax is not supported in the XQuery you are using:

```
for $dn in distinct-values(for $x in (/test/*) 
                           return local-name($x))
let $count := count(/test/*[local-name() = $dn])
order by $count descending
return ($dn, "-", $count, "occurrence(s) ")
```

The result from this is:

```
book - 3 occurrence(s) article - 2 occurrence(s) conference - 1 occurrence(s)
```

Comment: somehow it all the count occurrence is 0 

if i were to change it to the following its occurrence is all 1 only

for $dn in distinct-values(for $x in (/test/*) 
                           return local-name($x))
let $count := count($dn)
order by $count descending
return ($dn, "-", $count, "occurrence(s) ")

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand. Here is an "XQuery 3" solution :

```
for $x in (/test/*) 
    let $eltName := local-name($x)
    group by $eltName 
return ($eltName, "-",count($x), "occurrence(s) /")
```

For the XML provided, the result is :

```
conference - 1 occurrence(s) / book - 3 occurrence(s) / article - 2 occurrence(s) /
```